# Couldn't read larger data using snapshot in Cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In Cloud Firestore database due to excess docs under one collection the snapshot code which I usually use to read the docs isn't functioning. Please see the below code, this is how we are trying to read the data. During usage the App hangs causing the device to hang as well.

1. We already initialized the app and created firestoredb connection while loading our app by using below code.

````
    //firebase is a global namespace from which all Firebase services are accessed.
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

       //Initialize firebase database     
        firestoredb = firebase.firestore();

    // caches a copy of the Cloud Firestore data that your app is actively using, so your app can access the data when the device is offline
    //[START initialize_persistence]
    firebase.firestore().enablePersistence();

2.After this we are trying to read the data using the below code.      
```
 syncTagFromFirebase:function() {
      //Read Data From Cloud Firestore
      //Read data with onSnapshot  and docChanges and save the data in mySQL database
          firestoredb.collection('T5010_TAG').onSnapshot({
                        //Indicates whether metadata-only changes should trigger snapshot events.
                     includeMetadataChanges: true 
                    }, function (querySnapshot) {
                        querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(function (document) {
                            var source = querySnapshot.metadata.fromCache ? "Local Cache" : "FireBase Server";
                               if (source != "Local Cache") {  
                                if (document.type === "added") {
                                    db.transaction(function (tx, rs) {
                                        tx.executeSql("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO T5010_TAG(C5010_TAG_ID, C207_Set_Id, C901_Status,C5010_Void_Fl) VALUES (?,?,?,?) ", [document.doc.id,syncData.sid,syncData.sts,syncData.vfl]

                                         );
                                    });
                                }

                                if (document.type === "modified") {
                                    db.transaction(function (tx, rs) {
                                        tx.executeSql("UPDATE T5010_TAG SET C5010_TAG_ID=? ,C207_Set_Id=?,C901_Status=?,C5010_Void_Fl=? WHERE C5010_TAG_ID =?", [document.doc.id,syncData.sid,syncData.sts,syncData.vfl,document.doc.id]

                                    );
                                    });
                                }
                }

                        });
                    });

            },
````

Answer (score 0):

Loading all the documents makes app jerky since getting all the documents causes it to load in RAM, instead of loading all the documents in a particular collection, you can use [paging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors?authuser=1), loading documents only when needed
Looks like you storing the documents data locally in sqlite, you load documents in batches using paging and after storing in sqlite you can fetch next set of documents.
Firestore also supports [offline mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline?authuser=1), so no need to store the data in sqlite, check if offline data suits for your application